# Calculate matrix null space through rust nalgebra library

Tags: rust, linear-algebra, nalgebra

How can I get [the basis of the null space (kernel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix through the [rust nalgebra lib](https://nalgebra.org/docs/)?